# How can I convert pandas date time xticks to readable format?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a time series with a date time index.  The plot needs to be a particular size for the journal format.  Consequently, the sticks are not readable since they span many years.

Here is a data sample

```
2013-02-10  0.7714492098202259
2013-02-11  0.7709101833765016
2013-02-12  0.7704911332770049
2013-02-13  0.7694975914173087
2013-02-14  0.7692108921323576
```

The data is a series with a datetime index and spans from 2013 to 2016.  I use

```
data.plot(ax = ax)
```

to plot the  data.

How can I format my xticks to read like `'13` instead of `2013`?

Comment: FYI- you can also consider using `plt.tight_layout()`. This should adjust and fit the x labels.

Comment: @AndrewL No dice.  The sticks still collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some incompatibility between pandas and matplotlib formatters/locators when it comes to dates. See e.g. those questions:

- [Pandas plot - modify major and minor xticks for dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880333/pandas-plot-modify-major-and-minor-xticks-for-dates)
- [Pandas Dataframe line plot display date on xaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213781/pandas-dataframe-line-plot-display-date-on-xaxis)

I'm not entirely sure why it still works in some cases to use matplotlib formatters and not in others. However because of those issues, the bullet-proof solution is to use matplotlib to plot the graph instead of the pandas plotting function.
This allows to use locators and formatters just as seen in the [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html).

Here the solution to the question would look as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range("2013-01-01", "2017-06-20" )
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(dates)))

s = pd.Series(y, index=dates)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s.index, s.values)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("'%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearFmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html), you can do the following

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("'%y")
years = mdates.YearLocator() 
ax = df.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
```

[image]

Full work below

Add word value so pd.read_clipboard puts dates into index

```
value
2013-02-10  0.7714492098202259
2014-02-11  0.7709101833765016
2015-02-12  0.7704911332770049
2016-02-13  0.7694975914173087
2017-02-14  0.7692108921323576
```

Then read in data and convert index

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: After trying this, this is writing the year somewhere in the forties.

Comment: I changed your data to different years and this is the image I am getting.

Comment: The output from the code above is [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj90e.png) for me, with completely wrong years. @Ted can you provide a full working code that produces the plot you show?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just put the first column in the index and coverted it to a pandas timestamp. Could this be an issue with the date directive? I'm on a mac.

Comment: I don't know. To find out, it would be good to show your complete code. This would possibly provide an acceptable solution to this problem.